UNNotificationSound does not work. what is the problem?
import UIKit
import awesome_notifications
import shared_preferences_ios
import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
var alertController: UIAlertController?
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
        SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.register(
            with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.awesomenotifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin")!)
        FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.register(
            with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin")!)
    }

    requestNotificationAuthorization(application)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

    createRepeatableNotificationWithCustomSound()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

@objc func appDidBecomeActive() {
    print("App became active")
}

func requestNotificationAuthorization(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error {
                print("Notification authorization error: \(error)")
                return
            }

            if granted {
                print("Notification authorization granted")
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            } else {
                print("Notification authorization denied")
            }
        }
    }
}

func createRepeatableNotificationWithCustomSound() {
    print("createRepeatableNotificationWithCustomSound called")
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Custom Sound Notification"
    content.body = "This is a notification with a custom sound."

    if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "new", withExtension: "aiff") {
        print("Sound file found at path: \(soundURL.path)")
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("new.aiff"))
    } else {
        print("Sound file not found: new.aiff")
    }

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: "RepeatableCustomSoundNotification",
        content: content,
        trigger: trigger
    )

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to add notification: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Repeatable notification scheduled with custom sound.")
        }
    }
}

}
I wrote the code in delegate.swift using UNNotificationSound as shown above, but only the default iOS sound keeps playing repeatedly. What could be the problem? When written in Dart code, the registered sound plays correctly, but when the sound is deleted and UNNotificationSound is used, the registered sound does not play, and only the default sound plays.
